# how listen event when he run by javascript for dymanically content

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var input = $(<input type="text"/>)
$('body').append( input );
input.focus(); // Listen this event !

$(document).on('focus','input', function(){
alert('focus');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bORm/7zDGP/1/

Comment: Are you facing any troubles with that code? what is your question actually?

Comment: Yes, but alert not run, if I`am clicked to input, see alert

Comment: Run Forrest, run ...........

Comment: It works fine, your jsfiddle is working. Maybe your connection is slow and jquery was not loaded.

Comment: I am see alert when clicked to input but not run input.focus();

Comment: move ' input.focus(); '  under your event handler- it can't trigger the event function that has not yet been set

Comment: Rob Sedgwick, example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to trigger an event handler that has not yet been set, move the focus setter -

```
var input = $(<input type="text"/>);
$('body').append( input );


input.on('focus', function(){
alert('focus');
});

input.focus(); /* place it here, under your event handler */

/* another   */
input.trigger("focus");
```

edit/updated with a direct handler for the 'input'

Comment: Yup, this is the answer.

Comment: Thank, needed focus after Listen event